# Executing compiled jar file from .NET (System.Diagnostics.Process)

Tags: .net, vb.net, command-line, process, executable-jar

Trying to integrate the google closure compiler in a batch job of mine and having difficulty getting it to work.

Using command prompt I can enter the following command and get my scripts compiled. (The command is a self explanatory example)

```
java -jar "compiler.jar" --js_output_file="myOutput.min.js" --js="input1.js" --js="input2.js"
```

I have tried to replicate this using the System.Diagnostics.Process object but thus far have failed.

I have tried

```
Dim command As String = BuildCommand(CompilationScripts, Me._Output)
Dim process As New Process
process.Start("compiler.jar", command)
```

And I have tried

```
Dim command As String = BuildCommand(CompilationScripts, Me._Output)
Dim process As New Process
process.StartInfo.Arguments = command
process.Start("compiler.jar")
```

And I have tried

```
 Dim command As String = BuildCommand(CompilationScripts, Me._Output)
 Dim process As New Process
 process.StartInfo.Arguments = command
 process.Start("cmd.exe")
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: "...have failed". [How](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html)?

Comment: Sorry should have been more specific. Command prompt starts but no action is taken.

Answer (score 0):

`Arguments` should be

```
-jar "compiler.jar" --js_output_file="myOutput.min.js" --js="input1.js" --js="input2.js"
```

i.e. no `java` keyword here.

Also set

```
process.StartInfo.FileName = "java"
```

**EDIT**

```
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
process.StartInfo.FileName = "java"
```

Comment: Tried that just then but this just results in the folder C:\Windows\Java opening up

Comment: @Maxim Gershkovich updated the answer. try setting these properties too.