# Running a advanced java call from VB.net

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I need to run a small piece of Java code (Java is the only option in this case)

I have the jar file in the VB.net resources as `JSSMCL`(the extension is not required to run it, of this I am sure :P) I know I use `Path.GetFullPath(My.Resources.ResourceManager.BaseName)` 
but no mater how I do it it fails, I have tried so many ways i have lost count!

this is the command that I need to run:

```
java -cp "JSSMCL.jar" net.minecraft.MinecraftLauncher username false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `System.Diagnostics.Process` class and its method to start/run the `external` process.

Comment: i have tried that but it did nothing

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd", "cd " & Path.GetFullPath(My.Resources.ResourceManager.BaseName) & ";java -Xmx" & My.Settings.memory & "M -Xms" & My.Settings.memory & "M -cp ""/JSSMCL"" net.minecraft.MinecraftLauncher " & My.Settings.lastUsername & " false")

Comment: @user1000948 - May be something is missing. Can you post that code?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following code part to run the Command using `Process`

```
Sub Main()
    ' One file parameter to the executable
    Dim sourceName As String = "ExampleText.txt"
    ' The second file parameter to the executable
    Dim targetName As String = "Example.gz"

    ' New ProcessStartInfo created
    Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo

    ' Specify the location of the binary
    p.FileName = "C:\7za.exe"

    ' Use these arguments for the process
    p.Arguments = "a -tgzip """ & targetName & """ """ & sourceName & """ -mx=9"

    ' Use a hidden window
    p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

    ' Start the process
    Process.Start(p)
    End Sub
```

EDIT:

Use the Coding part like below, may be it works

```
-jar "compiler.jar" --js_output_file="myOutput.min.js" --js="input1.js" --js="input2.js"
```

Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930016/executing-compiled-jar-file-from-net-system-diagnostics-process) for your problem

Comment: Yes but how do i run my code
the file is halfway through the argument ??

Comment: i need to run a java file JSSMCL.jar
i Manuel run it from command line using:
java -cp "JSSMCL.jar" net.minecraft.MinecraftLauncher username false
i need my vb.net cod to run it for me
i have tried System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd", argument)
but it just displays a blank command line :(

Comment: Refer to this http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?t=166664 may be it will help.

Comment: @user1000948, what is exact error/problem you are getting in running the Jar file. The link which you provided is about Java itself right?

Comment: @user1000948, see the Edited part now.